# How to deploy http://code.google.com/p/dyuproject/ into app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, hybridauthprovider

I am trying to use openid/hybrid in app engine, but so far, no luck.

No success with openid4java (because it creates socket etc), and no luck with dyuproject either.

How do it deploy dyuproject into my java appengine? 
I just could not understand the different structure of the code in http://dyuproject.googlecode.com/files/dyuproject.appspot.com-source-2009-10-08.zip
It is just so different than the default new google web application.

Many thanks..

I have been struggling the whole week

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never. I'm working on [SixFixMix](http://code.google.com/p/sixfixmix/) and implemented a popup OpenID consumer. Check out its [Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/sixfixmix/wiki/OpenId) that gives a quick overview of my usage of OpenId.

Comment: thanks. I finally got it working, asked some questions to its author in google group.